# Elastic search dynamic aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index with products type, this product have all some common attributes, but depends on category have different attributes( i make a dinamyc mapping).

How is the best to mapping this and make after aggregation on them without knowing before how this field are named.

```
[specifications] => Array
                   (
                     [properties] => Array
                     (
                      [property1] => Array
                      (
                       [type] => string
                       [index] => not_analyzed
                      )
                      [property2] => Array
                      (
                       [type] => string
                       [index] => not_analyzed
                      ),
                      etc...
                      )
                     )
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:
mappping:

```
'attributes' => array(
                    'type' => 'nested',
                    'properties' => array(
                        'key' => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                        ),
                        'value' => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

aggs:

```
'attributes' => array(
                'nested' => array(
                    'path' => 'attributes',
                ),
                'aggs' => array(
                    'key' => array(
                        'terms' => array(
                            'field' => 'attributes.key',
                        ),
                        'aggs' => array(
                            'value' => array(
                                'terms' => array(
                                    'field' => 'attributes.value',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Comment: thanks i tweak as per ES 6.5 and get it working although i search various links and ES doc ..none was working. But this works fr me

Answer (score 0):

**Multi match** queries allows for **wildcard** fields.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#CO27-2

You can fiddle with some naming convention or isolate the fields you want to search in an object field (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html) and then use the widlcard to target those inner fields.

Comment: but i know how to search on those field but i don't know how to make dinamic aggs for those inner field considering that for every category page is other. I don't know if with elasticsearch is posible to set dinamic field aggregation for all subfields of a field or something